# Revit Add-in Localization

Tags: localization, revit-api

Is there a way with the API to convert/translate Revit standard terms such as 'Insulation', '3D view', 'View Templates', 'Detail Level'  and other baked-in terms to a given language (such as German, Russian , Chinese, etc.)? I'd like to ensure that the messages I provide in my localized add-in use terms that the user is familiar with (with regard to Revit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Autodesk localisation team uses a cross product corpus database NeXLT for terminology and message translation:

http://langtech.autodesk.com/nexlt

This link is accessible from outside the company and translation companies working with the localisation team around the world make use it for translating products for Autodesk platforms.

This answer is already published with a little more background on The Building Coder blog:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/10/autodesk-open-source-all-over-germany-and-japan.html#4

Answer (score 2):

I think Jeremy's answer is probably the way to go for a comprehensive approach.

However - if you're looking for something more self-contained and quick-and-dirty, you could try the LabelUtilities class in the Revit API. :)

The LabelUtilties lets you look up the translated value of all of the thousands of builtin parameters, parameter groups, unit types, etc).

All of the pieces of text that you mentioned above are available as BuiltInParmater translations (although, admittedly, some are not available as plurals).

For example:

LabelUtils.GetLabelFor( BuiltInParameter.RBS_WIRE_INSULATION_PARAM );

==> "Insulation" in English.

(You can see all of the translated English BuiltInParameters in the Revit API reference under the BuiltInParameters page).

Good Luck!
Matt